# TextFormat not working as intended initially

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

One of my text items (Score counter for a game) does not follow the format I have set when said text label has the value `0` but as soon as it updates to `1` or higher, the text is formatted correctly. When the score is `0`, the text is black and in Times New Roman font but then changes color, font and font size when it updates to `1` or higher. The problematic item in question is `scoreText.text`. This are the snippets of code that relates to the `scoreText` label:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {

static var scoreText:TextField = new TextField();

public var scoreFormat = new TextFormat("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20, 0xFFFFFF);

public function Main()
{
        addChild(gameLayer);
        addChild(backgroundLayer);
        addChild(interfaceLayer);
        interfaceLayer.addChild(mainMenu);
        soundControl = intro.play(0, 100);
        mainMenu.playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
}

public function startGame(e:Event)
{
    scoreText = new TextField();
    scoreText.text = String(0);
    interfaceLayer.addChild(scoreText);
    scoreText.x = 75;
    scoreText.y = 0;
    scoreText.selectable = false;

    scoreText.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);

    resetScore();
}

static function updateScore(points)
{
    score += points;
    scoreText.text = String(score);
    var scoreFormat = new TextFormat("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20, 0xFFFFFF);
    scoreHeader.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);
    scoreText.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);
}

static function resetScore()
{
    score = 0;
    scoreText.text = String(score);
}
```

If anyone could help pinpoint where I've went wrong I'd be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: I think it might be because you haven't assigned the TextFormat type to the scoreFormat variable. It should be.. `public var scoreFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20, 0xFFFFFF);` but I may be wrong (there could be other problems with your code)

Comment: I tried changing that but no dice unfortunately. It's annoying that such a small issue has left me stumped.

Comment: O.K, have you tried putting your `scoreText.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);` line outside of the functions so it is global. Try putting it at the top of the code alongside the other variable declarations and remove the `var scoreFormat = new TextFormat("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20, 0xFFFFFF);` line in `updateScore()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {

static var scoreText:TextField = new TextField();
static var scoreFormat = new TextFormat("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20, 0xFFFFFF);


public function Main()
{
        addChild(gameLayer);
        addChild(backgroundLayer);
        addChild(interfaceLayer);
        interfaceLayer.addChild(mainMenu);
        soundControl = intro.play(0, 100);
        mainMenu.playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
}

public function startGame(e:Event)
{
    scoreText.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);
    scoreText.text = String(0);
    interfaceLayer.addChild(scoreText);
    scoreText.x = 75;
    scoreText.y = 0;
    scoreText.selectable = false;
    resetScore();
}

static function updateScore(points)
{
    score += points;
    scoreText.text = String(score);
    scoreHeader.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);
}

static function resetScore()
{
    score = 0;
    scoreText.text = String(score);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `defaultTextFormat` of your TF, it'll save you jumps with text format.

```
public function startGame(e:Event)
{
    scoreText = new TextField();
    scoreText.defaultTextFormat=new TextFormat("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20, 0xFFFFFF);
    scoreText.text = String(0);
    interfaceLayer.addChild(scoreText);
    scoreText.x = 75;
    scoreText.y = 0;
    scoreText.selectable = false;
    resetScore();
}
```